# Empty columns or use a JOIN for MySQL

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have an image table and in the image table it has address of where images were taken.

There is maybe 300k images in table.

A lot of the addresses are emptry.

Is it quicker for me to seperate out the addresses and do a JOIN on the data? My thoughts are that there is less data to SELECT from but a JOIN is performed rather than keep the data in the current table:

```
select image, address from image_gallery
```

Comment: Please provide a sample schema/data.

Comment: From a logical standpoint, you'd probably want to separate out the addresses anyways (probably with a FK in the image table).  This would also severely limit the number of address records you have (I'm assuming multiple images were shot at the same address).  _Technically_ every `JOIN` _does_ eat some performance - however, for a well designed schema, with good indices, this isn't usually much of a factor.  DB Design recommends that you start with the 'proper' solution first (ie, separate tables), then move to denormalize the data only if there are performance issues.

Comment: I have longittude latitude, zoom yaw also so not likely address will be repeated more than once every image is a one to one in effect. So its better to have an address table with a join than address details in image_gallery table as there could be emptry columns in address

Comment: also how can i measure the speed to query in mysql